# Cross Sell discounts

Tags: magento-enterprise, discount, magento-1.14, cross-sells

We want to give discount at the Cross Sell pop-up when customer does an Add to Cart in the PDP page.  The cross sell pop should show discount amount and should be applied to the cart.

Rule would be:

- If the main product being added to cart has a value >= $29.99 then
  all the items in the cross sell are 50% off
- If the main product being added to cart has a value < $29.99 then all
  the items in the cross sell are 25% off

Can you please tell me how we can achieve this.?
Note: I am using Magento EE1.14.2.3

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "Shopping Cart Rule" in Conditions Add subtotal >= $29.99, After that in Actions set "Apply only" apply on items matching to your cross-sell item.

Note : It will only be shown when added to the cart.